# Fetching specific paths from neo4j Graph database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are using Neo4j 2.1.4 Community edition.

We are facing some issues in getting the specific paths in neo4j.

**Below is the csv file used.**

[image]

In graph database we are creating Product, Company,Country and Zipcode nodes along with the relationship type as ‘MyRel’ at each level.In the above data we wanted to differentiate each path ,

that is

Mobile, Google,US,88888 -- as path1

Mobile,Goolge,US -- as path2

Mobile,Goolge -- as path3

That’s why we created one more column called `Path` in data file and maintaining the `Path` value as a relatioship property. So whenever someone wants to see the different paths he can query based on Relationship property either 1 or 2 or 3. For eample , whenever we query for the relationship property, we should get `Mobile,Google ,US`

But whenever I do this , in graph it is creating dummy node for Country and Zipcode. This is due to in 2nd and 3rd row the zip and country values are empty(null).

**Query used:**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:\\WorkingFolder\\Neo4j\\EDGE_Graph_POC\\newdata\\trial1.csv " as file
MERGE (p:Product {Name:file.Product})
MERGE (comp:Company {Name:file.Company})
MERGE (c:Country {Name:file.Country})
MERGE (zip:Zipcode{Code:file.Zipcode})
CREATE (p)-[:MyRel{Path:file.Path}]->(comp)-[:MyRel{Path:file.Path}]->(c)-[:MyRel{Path:file.Path}]->(zip)
```

**Resultant graph:**

[image]

So how can I avoid creating dummy nodes ?

Is there any better alternative option to get the proper path?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

First, A simple solution is to follow the LOAD CSV query with others that clean up your graph. Run the queries

```
MATCH (zip:Zipcode { Code : ''})<-[r]-()
DELETE zip, r
```

and

```
MATCH (c:Country { Name : ''})<-[r]-()
DELETE c, r
```

You will then have the graph you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter them out with

```
WHERE file.Country <> '' and file.Zipcode <> ''
```

and split up your CREATE e.g.

```
CREATE (p)-[:MyRel{Path:file.Path}]->(comp)
WHERE file.Country <> '' and file.Zipcode <> ''
MERGE (c:Country {Name:file.Country})
MERGE (zip:Zipcode{Code:file.Zipcode})
CREATE (comp)-[:MyRel{Path:file.Path}]->(c)-[:MyRel{Path:file.Path}]->(zip)
```